# how to make a modal div appear and disappear via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

this is the js code that is supposed to make the modal div appear and disappear, the modal div (pr_ball0) is hidden by default via css using the aforementioned id

```js
function setStile(){
  document.getElementById('pr_ball0').style.visibility="visible";
  } 
 function hide(){
  document.getElementById("myHide1").style.visibility="hidden";
 }
```

```css
this is the css code which make the  balls work 
/* [Object] Modal
 * =============================== */
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz);
.ball {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .9);
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  padding: 40px;
}

.ball_bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ball-state {
  display: none;
}

.ball-state:checked + .ball {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal-state:checked + .ball .pr_inner {
  top: 0;
}
.pr_ball
{
  transition: top .25s ease;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  top: -2%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
#pr_ball0 {
  
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #F2E357 0%, #F2EB1B 100%);
  visibility: hidden;
}

#pr_ball1 {
  
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center, #D6D696 0%, #EFEFB1 100%);
 
}

#pr_ball2 {

  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center, #D6D262 0%, #8CCF59 100%);
}

#pr_ball3 {
  
  
  
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center, #B3F2AE 0%, #DBF2C2 100%);
 
}

#pr_ball4 {
  
  

  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #D69C15 0%, #F7E334 100%);
 
}

#pr_ball5 {
  
  
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #F2816A 0%, #F2B28C 100%);
 
}

#pr_ball6 {
  
  
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #F2CD8C 0%, #EBF2C6 100%);

}

#pr_ball7 {
  
  
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #D6D2D3 0%, #BAB3BA 100%);
 
}

#pr_ball8 {
  
  
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #C7F2EC 0%, #DAF1F2 100%);

}

#pr_ball9 {
  
 
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #D6D2D3 0%, #F7CBCF 100%);

}

#pr_ball10 {
  
  
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #D6D2D3 0%, #D394F7 100%);
  border-radius: 100%;

}

.ball_close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
  top: 5%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: rgba(233, 25, 25, 1) 10px 10px 10px;
}

.ball_close:after,
.ball_close:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 1.5em;
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(245, 12, 12, 1);
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 50%;
  margin: -3px 0 0 -1px;
  top: 0;
}

.ball_close:hover:after,
.ball_close:hover:before {
  background: #aaa;
}

.ball_close:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 
  .pr_inner {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}


/* Other
 * =============================== */
body {
  padding:  50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn:hover{
opacity: 0.5;
}

#pr_btn0 {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 270px;
left: 300px;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 300px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-color: yellow;
}
#pr_btn0:hover{
opacity: 0.4;
}

#pr_btn1 {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 240px;
left: 215px;
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center, #D6D696 0%, #EFEFB1 100%);
}

#pr_btn2 {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 280px;
left: 130px;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center, #D6D262 0%, #8CCF59 100%);
}

#pr_btn3 {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 210px;
left: 10px;
width: 90px;
height: 70px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center, #B3F2AE 0%, #DBF2C2 100%);
}

#pr_btn4 {
  cursor: pointer;
background: #4c74be;
position: absolute;
top: 390px;
left: 110px;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #D69C15 0%, #F7E334 100%);
}

#pr_btn5 {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
top: 410px;
left: 10px;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #F2816A 0%, #F2B28C 100%);
}

#pr_btn6 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #4c74be;
position: absolute;
top: 400px;
left: 220px;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #F2CD8C 0%, #EBF2C6 100%);
}

#pr_btn7 {
  cursor: pointer;
 background: #4c74be;
position: absolute;
top: 390px;
left: 435px;
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #D6D2D3 0%, #BAB3BA 100%);
}

#pr_btn8 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #4c74be;
position: absolute;
top: 420px;
left: 565px;
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #C7F2EC 0%, #DAF1F2 100%);
}

#pr_btn9 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #4c74be;
position: absolute;
top: 345px;
left: 515px;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #D6D2D3 0%, #F7CBCF 100%);
}

#pr_btn10 {
  cursor: pointer;
 background: #4c74be;
position: absolute;
top: 210px;
left: 515px;
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #D6D2D3 0%, #D394F7 100%);
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  background: #2ecc71;
}

.btn:active {
  background: #27ae60;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .2) inset;
}

.btn--blue {
  background: #2980b9;
}

.btn--blue:hover,
.btn--blue:focus {
  background: #3498db;
}

.btn--blue:active {
  background: #2980b9;
}

p img {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}

#pr_ball7 {
  
  
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #D6D2D3 0%, #BAB3BA 100%);
 
}

#pr_ball8 {
  
  
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #C7F2EC 0%, #DAF1F2 100%);

}

#pr_ball9 {
  
 
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #D6D2D3 0%, #F7CBCF 100%);

}

#pr_ball10 {
  
  
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #D6D2D3 0%, #D394F7 100%);
  border-radius: 100%;

}

.ball_close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
  top: 5%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: rgba(233, 25, 25, 1) 10px 10px 10px;
}

.ball_close:after,
.ball_close:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 1.5em;
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(245, 12, 12, 1);
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 50%;
  margin: -3px 0 0 -1px;
  top: 0;
}

.ball_close:hover:after,
.ball_close:hover:before {
  background: #aaa;
}

.ball_close:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 
  .ball {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}


/* Other
 * =============================== */
body {
  padding:  50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pr_ball:hover{
opacity: 0.5;
}

#pr_btn0 {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 270px;
left: 300px;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 300px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-color: yellow;
}
#pr_btn0:hover{
opacity: 0.4;
}

#pr_btn1 {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 240px;
left: 215px;
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center, #D6D696 0%, #EFEFB1 100%);
}

#pr_btn2 {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 280px;
left: 130px;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center, #D6D262 0%, #8CCF59 100%);
}

#pr_btn3 {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 210px;
left: 10px;
width: 90px;
height: 70px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at center, #B3F2AE 0%, #DBF2C2 100%);
}

#pr_btn4 {
  cursor: pointer;
background: #4c74be;
position: absolute;
top: 390px;
left: 110px;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #D69C15 0%, #F7E334 100%);
}

#pr_btn5 {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
top: 410px;
left: 10px;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #F2816A 0%, #F2B28C 100%);
}

#pr_btn6 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #4c74be;
position: absolute;
top: 400px;
left: 220px;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #F2CD8C 0%, #EBF2C6 100%);
}

#pr_btn7 {
  cursor: pointer;
 background: #4c74be;
position: absolute;
top: 390px;
left: 435px;
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #D6D2D3 0%, #BAB3BA 100%);
}

#pr_btn8 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #4c74be;
position: absolute;
top: 420px;
left: 565px;
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #C7F2EC 0%, #DAF1F2 100%);
}

#pr_btn9 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #4c74be;
position: absolute;
top: 345px;
left: 515px;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #D6D2D3 0%, #F7CBCF 100%);
}

#pr_btn10 {
  cursor: pointer;
 background: #4c74be;
position: absolute;
top: 210px;
left: 515px;
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
padding: 30px;
border-radius: 150px;
box-shadow: #cccccc 10px 10px 10px;
background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center, #D6D2D3 0%, #D394F7 100%);
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  background: #2ecc71;
}

.btn:active {
  background: #27ae60;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .2) inset;
}

.btn--blue {
  background: #2980b9;
}

.btn--blue:hover,
.btn--blue:focus {
  background: #3498db;
}

.btn--blue:active {
  background: #2980b9;
}

p img {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
```

```html
this is the html code which through external css and js is supposed to work

<div id="contenitore">
 <label id="pr_btn0" class="pr_ball" for="modal-0" onclick="setStile()">DIV 0</label>
 <label id="pr_btn1" class="pr_ball" for="modal-1">DIV 1</label>
 <label id="pr_btn2" class="pr_ball" for="modal-2">DIV 2</label>
 <label id="pr_btn3" class="pr_ball" for="modal-3">DIV 3</label>
 <label id="pr_btn4" class="pr_ball" for="modal-4">DIV 4</label>
 <label id="pr_btn5" class="pr_ball" for="modal-5">DIV 5</label>
 <label id="pr_btn6" class="pr_ball" for="modal-6">DIV 6</label>
 <label id="pr_btn7" class="pr_ball" for="modal-7">DIV 7</label>
 <label id="pr_btn8" class="pr_ball" for="modal-8">DIV 8</label>
 <label id="pr_btn9" class="pr_ball" for="modal-9">DIV 9</label>
 <label id="pr_btn10" class="pr_ball" for="modal-10">DIV 10</label>
 </div>

    <input class="ball-state" id="modal-0" type="checkbox" />
 <div class="ball">
   <label class="ball_bg" for="modal-0"></label>
   <div id="pr_ball0" class="pr_ball">
  <label id="myHide1" class="ball_close" onclick="hide()" for="modal-0"></label>
  <h2>Caaaats FTW!</h2>
  <p>Aliquam in sagittis nulla. Curabitur euismod diam eget risus venenatis, sed dictum lectus bibendum. Nunc nunc nisi, hendrerit eget nisi id, rhoncus rutrum velit. Nunc vel mauris dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam fringilla quis nisi eget imperdiet.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <input class="ball-state" id="modal-1" type="checkbox" />
 <div class="ball">
   <label class="ball_bg" for="modal-1"></label>
   <div id="pr_ball1" class="pr_ball">
  <label class="ball_close" for="modal-1"></label>
  <h2>Caaaats FTW!</h2>
  <p>Aliquam in sagittis nulla. Curabitur euismod diam eget risus venenatis, sed dictum lectus bibendum. Nunc nunc nisi, hendrerit eget nisi id, rhoncus rutrum velit. Nunc vel mauris dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam fringilla quis nisi eget imperdiet.</p>
   </div>
 </div>

 <input class="ball-state" id="modal-2" type="checkbox" />
 <div class="ball">
   <label class="ball_bg" for="modal-2"></label>
   <div id="pr_ball2" class="pr_ball">
  <label class="ball_close" for="modal-2"></label>
  <h2>Caaaats FTW!</h2>
  <p>Aliquam in sagittis nulla. Curabitur euismod diam eget risus venenatis, sed dictum lectus bibendum. Nunc nunc nisi, hendrerit eget nisi id, rhoncus rutrum velit. Nunc vel mauris dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam fringilla quis nisi eget imperdiet.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <input class="ball-state" id="modal-3" type="checkbox" />
 <div class="ball">
   <label class="ball_bg" for="modal-3"></label>
   <div id="pr_ball3" class="pr_ball">
  <label class="ball_close" for="modal-3"></label>
  <h2>Caaaats FTW!</h2>
  <p>Aliquam in sagittis nulla. Curabitur euismod diam eget risus venenatis, sed dictum lectus bibendum. Nunc nunc nisi, hendrerit eget nisi id, rhoncus rutrum velit. Nunc vel mauris dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam fringilla quis nisi eget imperdiet.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <input class="ball-state" id="modal-4" type="checkbox" />
 <div class="ball">
   <label class="ball_bg" for="modal-4"></label>
   <div id="pr_ball4" class="pr_ball">
  <label class="ball_close" for="modal-4"></label>
  <h2>Caaaats FTW!</h2>
  <p>Aliquam in sagittis nulla. Curabitur euismod diam eget risus venenatis, sed dictum lectus bibendum. Nunc nunc nisi, hendrerit eget nisi id, rhoncus rutrum velit. Nunc vel mauris dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam fringilla quis nisi eget imperdiet.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <input class="ball-state" id="modal-5" type="checkbox" />
 <div class="ball">
   <label class="ball_bg" for="modal-5"></label>
   <div id="pr_ball5" class="pr_ball">
  <label class="ball_close" for="modal-5"></label>
  <h2>Caaaats FTW!</h2>
  <p>Aliquam in sagittis nulla. Curabitur euismod diam eget risus venenatis, sed dictum lectus bibendum. Nunc nunc nisi, hendrerit eget nisi id, rhoncus rutrum velit. Nunc vel mauris dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam fringilla quis nisi eget imperdiet.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <input class="ball-state" id="modal-6" type="checkbox" />
 <div class="ball">
   <label class="ball_bg" for="modal-6"></label>
   <div id="pr_ball6" class="pr_ball">
  <label class="ball_close" for="modal-6"></label>
  <h2>Caaaats FTW!</h2>
  <p>Aliquam in sagittis nulla. Curabitur euismod diam eget risus venenatis, sed dictum lectus bibendum. Nunc nunc nisi, hendrerit eget nisi id, rhoncus rutrum velit. Nunc vel mauris dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam fringilla quis nisi eget imperdiet.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <input class="ball-state" id="modal-7" type="checkbox" />
 <div class="ball">
   <label class="ball_bg" for="modal-7"></label>
   <div id="pr_ball7" class="pr_ball">
  <label class="ball_close" for="modal-7"></label>
  <h2>Caaaats FTW!</h2>
  <p>Aliquam in sagittis nulla. Curabitur euismod diam eget risus venenatis, sed dictum lectus bibendum. Nunc nunc nisi, hendrerit eget nisi id, rhoncus rutrum velit. Nunc vel mauris dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam fringilla quis nisi eget imperdiet.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <input class="ball-state" id="modal-8" type="checkbox" />
 <div class="ball">
   <label class="ball_bg" for="modal-8"></label>
   <div id="pr_ball8" class="pr_ball">
  <label class="ball_close" for="modal-8"></label>
  <h2>Caaaats FTW!</h2>
  <p>Aliquam in sagittis nulla. Curabitur euismod diam eget risus venenatis, sed dictum lectus bibendum. Nunc nunc nisi, hendrerit eget nisi id, rhoncus rutrum velit. Nunc vel mauris dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam fringilla quis nisi eget imperdiet.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <input class="ball-state" id="modal-9" type="checkbox" />
 <div class="ball">
   <label class="ball_bg" for="modal-9"></label>
   <div id="pr_ball9" class="pr_ball">
  <label class="ball_close" for="modal-9"></label>
  <h2>Caaaats FTW!</h2>
  <p>Aliquam in sagittis nulla. Curabitur euismod diam eget risus venenatis, sed dictum lectus bibendum. Nunc nunc nisi, hendrerit eget nisi id, rhoncus rutrum velit. Nunc vel mauris dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam fringilla quis nisi eget imperdiet.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
 
 <input class="ball-state" id="modal-10" type="checkbox" />
 <div class="ball">
   <label class="ball_bg" for="modal-10"></label>
   <div id="pr_ball10" class="pr_ball">
  <label class="ball_close" for="modal-10"></label>
  <h2>Caaaats FTW!</h2>
  <p>Aliquam in sagittis nulla. Curabitur euismod diam eget risus venenatis, sed dictum lectus bibendum. Nunc nunc nisi, hendrerit eget nisi id, rhoncus rutrum velit. Nunc vel mauris dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam fringilla quis nisi eget imperdiet.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

here

Comment: Are you doing this is pure Javascript or jQuery as well?

Comment: pure javascript css3 and html5 i'm not definitely using jquery, please help me to solve this issue, I've been trying it for weeks

Comment: remove the `visibility: hidden;` from `.ball` class as you have added visibility on two place in css.

Comment: as a matter of fact my purpose is to make a given modal div visible somehow i would like to pop it up by clicking on the smaller one defined in the label element of the html part, have I been clear enough?  I am aware that I must be as clear as possible and this issue is not clear at all -my fault

Comment: I've tried to remove the visibility: hidden but i always have the same problem, once i make appear the modal div and i prass the x on top right I close it but I can't open it again